# SQL Insert Into ColX Table 1 Select ColY from table 2 where Table1.colA=Table2.ColB

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm much more a java than a sql developer. I have looked on SO for this, but for some reason cannot find a question with similar WHERE criteria

In PostgreSQL, the following syntax is incorrect

```
INSERT INTO contentelementtypeprogressortype  (contentelementtypeclassname)
SELECT contentelementtypename FROM contentelementtype
WHERE
contentelementtype.id=contentelementtypeprogressortype.contentelementtypeid
```

The error is:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "contentelementtypeprogressortype"
>   LINE 2: ...OM contentelementtype where contentelementtype.id=contentele...
>                                                                ^
>   HINT:  There is an entry for table "contentelementtypeprogressortype", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "contentelementtypeprogressortype"
>   SQL state: 42P01
>   Hint: There is an entry for table "contentelementtypeprogressortype", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
>   Character: 159

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO contentelementtypeprogressortype(contentelementtypeclassname)
    SELECT cet.contentelementtypename
    FROM contentelementtype  cet
    WHERE cet.id = contentelementtypeprogressortype.contentelementtypeid;
```

I don't think you really want an `INSERT` -- this adds a new row.  I think you really want an `UPDATE`, which changes a value in an existing row:

```
UPDATE contentelementtypeprogressortype cetpt
    SET contentelementtypeclassname = cet.contentelementtypename
    FROM contentelementtype  cet
    WHERE cet.id = cetpt.contentelementtypeid;
```